# Is the cross product or the scalar product implied if neither are explicitly used in an expression?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, soft-question

For example, does the expression 
$ab$
imply
$a \cdot b$
or
$a \times b$
,what about the expression 
$\vec a \vec b$
, does this imply 
$\vec a \cdot \vec b$ 
or 
$\vec a \times \vec b$ 
? What if brackets are included: 
$\vec a (\vec b)$?

Comment: This all depends on the context, so it is almost impossible to answer. But, I would **not** expect $ab$ to mean $a\times b$.

Comment: I have never seen the notation $\vec a\,\vec b$.  I have no guess as to what it might mean.  Can you supply a reference to its use?

Comment: Where have you seen this? In the context of linear algebra I would say that writing $ab$ for the scalar product is bad notation and writing $ab$ for the cross product is very bad notation. In other contexts, e.g. when one is studying algebraic properties of the ring $(\mathbb{R}^3,\times)$ I assume one can justify leaving the product sign away, when it is clear which product is meant.

Comment: The dot product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could mean just a [dyadic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics) product, if $\vec{a} = a_x \hat{x} + a_y \hat{y} + a_z \hat{z}$ and $\vec{b} = b_x \hat{x} + b_y \hat{y} + b_z \hat{z}$, then

\begin{eqnarray}
\vec{a}\vec{b} &=& (a_x \hat{x} + a_y \hat{y} + a_z \hat{z})(b_x \hat{x} + b_y \hat{y} + b_z \hat{z}) \\
&=& a_xb_x \hat{x}\hat{x} + a_xb_y\hat{x}\hat{y} + a_xb_z\hat{x}\hat{z} \\
&& + a_yb_x \hat{y}\hat{x} + a_yb_y\hat{y}\hat{y} + a_yb_z\hat{y}\hat{z} \\
&& +a_zb_x \hat{z}\hat{x} + a_zb_y\hat{z}\hat{y} + a_zb_z\hat{z}\hat{z} \\
\end{eqnarray}

This is just tensor product

Comment: (+1) This is actually rather common in older literature, especially in relation to continuum mechanics.

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić That's where I learned about it :)